# Redirecting to another page conditionally and sending parameters through POST in PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I have a page which takes input data from users trying to create a new account on my website. Although I want to check the values of the data before the page is redirected to send the input data to the database. I have created a verification form which redirects back to the same page when the user clicks submit, so as to check the values, but if all the values are okay, then I want to send the parameters inputted to another page which will input them in the database. Is there a way to do this conditionally in PHP? I've tried to implement it with a simple boolean checking if any of the parameters inputted are incorrect, but don't know how to send the params along with the redirection.

Here is a shortened version of the code with just some of the forms:

```
<?php
// Connection to database
include_once("createConnection.php");

$hasErrors = false;
$errorFName = $errorLName = $errorEmail = "";
$fName = $lName = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fName"])) {
    $errorFName = "This field is required.";
    $hasErrors = true;
} 
else {
    $name = validation($_POST["fName"]);
    //name cannot contain any symbols or numbers
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fName)) {
      $errorFName = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      $hasErrors = true;
    }
}

if($hasErrors==false){
    **???**
}


function validation($input) { 
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    return $input;
}
?>

<form class="loginForm" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <table class="loginTable">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="newDetail">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="formBox" value="" id="newDetail" name="fName">
                <?php echo $errorFName;?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="newDetail">Password: </label>
                <input type="text" class="formBox" value="" id="newDetail" name="pword">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" class="loginButton" name="submitNew">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the $_POST variables in sessions.

```
$_SESSION["firstname"] = $_POST["fname"];
```

Then redirect to the required page

```
header("location: welcomepage.php");
```

Then grab the variables from the session and process, maybe insert to database for future use.

```
$firstname = $_SESSION["firstname"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect manually with a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0, welcomepage.php?params=params">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you would like to pass parameters to other page - it qould be much easier to process them right here. If it is a general messines of the code you dislike - you can pass data to a function or a method from an included file.

However, if it is *really necessary* to save data from a separate page I would recommend sending them via `cURL`:

```
$post          = array(/*put all your variables here*/);
$params        = http_build_query($post);
$url           = 'http://your.domain.com/receiver.php';
$curl          = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result        = curl_exec($curl);
```

This way anything you would output on the receiving page will end up in `$result`, so you can confirm to a user that his/her data was saved.

**NB:** whatever you would end up doing - do NOT pass the data to the receiving page as GET. It is insecure and every time someone does this a puppy dies!

More info on curl: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thanks for this I will give it a try. Is your code above sending the parameters as an array which can be extracted through $params on the destination page? For example on receiver.php:

    $firstName=$params["fName'];

or through POST? as in:

    $firstName=$_POST["fName"];     ?

Comment: do you know which one it is?

Comment: @AndrewY, it would be in $_POST array. So, if you have done `$post = array('checked_fName'=>$_POST['fName']);` at the main page, at `receiver.php` you'll get `$firstName = $_POST['checked_fName'];`

Comment: @AndrewY If this answer solved your issue, please award it the green tick.  Please help future SO readers to quickly identify the "best" answer when they are sent to this page.